# How many times does vector go from 0 to non-zero

Tags: r

Let's say I have a vector like `hours <- c( 200,200,0,0,0,100,100,100,0,100)` and I want to count how many times it goes from 0 to a non-zero.

For example we could do

```
starts<-0
for(i in 1:(length(hours)-1)) {
  if(hours[i]==0 & hours[i+1]!=0) starts<-starts+1
}
```

That doesn't feel very R like, is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `diff`.

```
sum(diff(hours != 0) == 1) 
# [1] 2
```

Explanation:

The number of times (`sum` of) differences (`diff`) in "non-zero-ness" (`!= 0`) exist (`== 1`).

Comment: This counts the jumps from non-zero to 0. They're asking for from 0 to non-zero.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it.

Comment: I like this solution best (+1)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `rle`:

```
hours <- c( 200,200,0,0,0,100,100,100,0,100)
runs <- rle(hours)
sum(runs$values == 0) - ifelse(tail(hours,1) == 0,1,0)
#evaluates to 2
```

The logic is that the number of transitions from `0` is the number of non-terminal runs of `0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
sum(hours == 0 & lead(hours) != 0)
```

Comment: lead isn't a base R function

Comment: dplyr would probably be better to pull than the full tidyverse just for the single function

Comment: I prefer to think of it as helping ;)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Jordo's answer but without using an extra library.

`sum(hours[1:(length(hours)-1)]==0&hours[2:(length(hours))]!=0)`

Comment: You could use `head(x, -1)` and `tail(x, -1)` to get the desired vectors